# Add double quotes to list of strings

Tags: groovy

I've got a list in groovy lets say:

```
[one, two, three]
```

Now I want to add double quotes to the strings of this array so that the final result would be:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Note that I do want the square brackets to be included as well. How can I do that in Groovy in the most comprehensive way?

EDIT: I'm using groovy templating inside html code and I just want a string in the exact format I described above

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also if you need this for some sort of (de)serialization, then don't use toString, inspect, ... - go for something, that is actually up to the task.

Comment: I'm using groovy templating inside html code and I just want a string in the format I mentioned above. the `inspect()` method added single quotes instead of doubles

Answer (score 20, accepted):

so if you have:

```
def list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Then you can do:

```
List modifiedList = list.collect{ '"' + it + '"'}
```

output : `["one", "two", "three"]`

Comment: Awesome! That's the answer I've been looking for. Simple and straightforward thanks

Comment: Groovier maybe - "\"$it\""

Comment: this is awesome. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

so if you have:

```
def list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Then you can do:

```
String strList = list.inspect()
```

To get the list quoted and with square brackets

An alternative would also be to do:

```
String strList = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(list).toString()
```

Which will give you the same, but in json format (with double quotes)

Comment: Almost there. The `inspect()` method added single quotes to the strings. Gonna try the json thing too

Comment: @ThanosF above code works as described.  If you get errors, add them to the question with your attempts.  "does not work" is not enough to help you.

Comment: I'm using groovy templating inside html code and I just want a string in the exact format I described above. As I said the `inspect()` method adds single quotes instead of doubles and the JsonBuilder class in non existent in the groovy templating

Comment: What do you mean _"non existent"_?  What version of Groovy are you running?  1.8?

Comment: No I'm using 2.1.2 but for some reason JsonBuilder couldn't be found when called from html code. Anyway I found a work around. Check my answer and thanks so much for the `inspect()` method it really helped

Comment: Your answer won't work if you have things containing single quotes

Comment: If you shore what you're doing in the question, we'll be able to tell you what you're missing to get it to work

Comment: Is it possible to loop over a list, and add quotes to only numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Since `inspect()` method adds single quotes instead of doubles in groovy templating for some reason, best solution I came up with is this

```
${myList.inspect().replaceAll("\'", "\"")}
```

output:
`["one", "two", "three"]`

My solution along with Prakash solution are the only ones that worked for me.

Comment: As stated in comments to the @tim_yates answer - it will mangle values which have single quotes itself:
```def list = ['one', 'two', 'three', "some 'other'"]
String strList = list.inspect().replaceAll("\'", "\"")```
Will produce: `["one", "two", "three", "some \"other\""]`. So quotes in values also replaced.